# SSIS Package - How can I import datatable from Excel source instead of entire sheet

Tags: c#, ssis

I will try to explain being the most understandable my concern :

I am creating an SSIS package importing data from Excel source and load it to SQL table.

I can retreive the data using sheet name without problem, but this package is looping through several excel files with different sheet names, sheet position (for file X the sheet index is 0, for file Y sheet index is 4 and so on) so I need to get data table name (the name is the same for all excel files but dimension is different.)

Here is what I want to retreive :[Excel file composition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7OOS.png)

- Green = Data table name (name that I want to get in SSIS package)
- Yellow = Data table content (data stored in the table, only data that I want to get)
- Red = Sheet name (Default information that I retreive in the package, but not adapted to the need here)

I have set up a Srcipt Task to get all tables stored in that excel file with the following code :

```
                string excelFile;
                string connectionString;
                OleDbConnection excelConnection;
                DataTable tablesInFile;
                string currentTable;
                int tableIndex = 0;

                string[] excelTables = new string[5];

                excelFile = Dts.Variables["FileName"].Value.ToString();

                connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;\"", excelFile);
                excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                excelConnection.Open();

                tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

                foreach (DataRow tableInFile in tablesInFile.Rows)
                {
                    currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    excelTables[tableIndex] = currentTable;
                    tableIndex += 1;
                }

                Dts.Variables["ExcelTables"].Value = excelTables;
```

But here is the result I got after execution : only 'Sheet1$' value is stored, and no news from my data table :(
[Displayed tables after running that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMBAn.png)

Please give me a hand with that topic

Comment: To restate the problem: I need to be able to examine all worksheets in an Excel workbook. Within the worksheets, I need to find specific tables and then extract that data.  Do I have this correct?

Comment: If my interpretation of the requirements are correct, how do you "know" which Table you need to use, assuming there can be more than one across the variable number of worksheets in the notebook?

Comment: You are right, Worksheets have a name that I can retreive thanks to specific characters in the file name (for file ABCD.xlsx --> worksheet name is [ABCD Sheet$])
I have a C# script already created to get the sheetname I want to work on, but then I fail to get the datatable named "MyTable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For them who would met the same issue one day, here is how I have worked to get data from datatable :

- 1st I created Script Component inside of a Data Flow Task and set up the Script component by creating as many output columns that I have columns in my datatable under the Inputs and Outputs section
  [Script Component set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtiD0.png) (don't forger to set the data type of your column in the Data Type Properties on right of the window)
- Then I created the script :

  - First add Excel COM reference :
    -> Click the Edit Script button in the Script Component
    -> On right of the screen, right-click on "References" and "Add Reference..."
    -> In the COM libraby, search for "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library" and and check the box, click OK.
  - You need to use this Object library by adding this line in the Namespaces section at the begining of your code :

> using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

- After that you can paste the code and adapt it to your need :

> public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
> {
> // Var ExcelFilePath = Path to excel file
> string excelFilePath = Variables.FilePath;
>
> ```
>     // Create new excel instance
>     Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
>
>     // Open Excel file
>     Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
>
>     // Set table to empty for the moment
>     Excel.ListObject table = null;
>
>     // For each sheet in excel file...
>     foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in excelWorkbook.Sheets)
>     {
>         // For each object in the sheet...
>         foreach (Excel.ListObject tbl in sheet.ListObjects)
>         {
>             // If object name is equal to the table name provided
>             if (tbl.Name == "MyTable")
>             {
>                 // Var table = table name
>                 table = tbl;
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
>         // If table has been found then we get out the loop, else we search in another sheet
>         if (table != null)
>         {
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     // If the table is not empty
>     if (table != null)
>     {
>
>         // For each row in the table...
>         foreach (Excel.ListRow row in table.ListRows)
>         {
>             // Add new row
>             Output0Buffer.AddRow();
>                 // Insert in output table (Column1..ColumnX) --> value of table from excel sheet 1..X
>                 Output0Buffer.Column1 = Convert.ToString(row.Range[1, 1].Value2);
>                 Output0Buffer.Column2 = Convert.ToString(row.Range[1, 2].Value2);
>                 Output0Buffer.Column3 = Convert.ToString(row.Range[1, 3].Value2);
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     // Close excel file
>     excelWorkbook.Close(0);
>
>     // Quit excel application
>     excelApp.Quit();
> ```
>
> }

- Now that you get this, your Script component act like a normal data source excepted that now you just retrieved data from your defined data table.

IMPORTANT :

- Please note that in order to do that you need to have Office installed on your machine.
- Please consider that Micrsosoft does not support this way to proceed as it consider that Excel should be use by humains, not machines, so please use this only if you have no other alternatives (such as csv or xml files, EPPlus, OleDB, etc. whch are way more efficicent and quicker)